# Python program run forever using Queue and Thread

Tags: python, python-multithreading

I'm using [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and [Thread](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) to create a program that runs multiple light threads based on an objects list with limitation of the number of the workers to 3.

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

def worker(q_objects, q_objects_adj):
    return q_objects.get(), q_objects_adj.get()
    
def get_obj_adj(object):
    return f"{object}_adj"

objects_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']

q_objects = Queue()
q_objects_adj = Queue()

for i in range(3):
     t = Thread(target=worker, args=[q_objects, q_objects_adj], daemon=True)
     t.start()

for obj in objects_list:
    q_objects.put(obj)
    q_objects_adj.put(get_obj_adj(obj))

q_objects.join() 
#q_objects_adj.join()
```

The program is running forever now without any return. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: What is it that you want your program to accomplish? Your `worker()` threads will quickly exit, leaving items left on your queues which will leave the statement `q_objects.join()` blocked forever.

Comment: why are you joining the `queue` and not the `workers`, you should be joining the workers instead, why are you joining ? what are you waiting for ?

Comment: You probably need your threads to run continuously until you (somehow) tell them to stop. When the thread function (worker) executes *return*, that thread terminates. What output are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @Codist What I'll usually do here is fill the `Queue` before starting the threads. Then each thread loops until the `Queue` is empty, then returns. And finally, of course, in `main`, finish be joining all of the threads.

Comment: @JamesKanze Isn't that rather inefficient? Surely it's better to let your threads do their work as you're acquiring the input data (what you're loading on the queue(s))

Comment: @quamrana I want worker() to be executed in parallel for every 3 objects simultaneously in the list objects_list (and not to execute it in parallel for all the objects in objects_list) and return every obj and its obj_adj. That's why I'm using multithreading.

Comment: Do you mean that each worker executes for their first object, but waits for the others to finish before their next object? Plus what do you mean by `"return every obj ... "`? Threads don't ever return anything.

Comment: @Codist It depends on the application. In my case, the "jobs" were read from a file, and each job took anywhere between 10 ms and 5 sec., so that wasn't a problem. So I chose the simplest solution. (I did need something similar about 15 years ago, where the "jobs" were in response to an external event. But that was in C++, where I had to implement my own queue, and made provisions for a special flag to shut it down.)

Comment: @NewUser If you have 3 threads each consuming messages from the same queue, you cannot be certain that publishing 3 messages to that queue will be handled by each of the 3 threads. Why would you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok since you edited your original code I edited as well, here is my new answer :

```py
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue
import time

def worker(thread_id, q_objects, q_objects_adj):
    print("Thread", thread_id, "starts")
    while not q_objects.empty():
        data = q_objects.get(), q_objects_adj.get()
        print("Thread", thread_id, data)
        q_objects.task_done()
        q_objects_adj.task_done()
        time.sleep(0.01)
    print("Thread", thread_id, "ends")
    return

def get_obj_adj(obj):
    return f"{obj}_adj"

objects_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p']

q_objects = Queue()
q_objects_adj = Queue()

for obj in objects_list:
    q_objects.put(obj)
    q_objects_adj.put(get_obj_adj(obj))

print("Start")
for i in range(3):
     t = Thread(target=worker, args=[i, q_objects, q_objects_adj], daemon=True)
     t.start()
q_objects.join()
q_objects_adj.join()
print("End")
```

And the restult here :

```
Start
Thread 0 starts
Thread 0 ('a', 'a_adj')
Thread 1 starts
Thread 2 starts
Thread 1 ('b', 'b_adj')
Thread 2 ('c', 'c_adj')
Thread 1 ('d', 'd_adj')
Thread 0 ('e', 'e_adj')
Thread 2 ('f', 'f_adj')
Thread 1 ('g', 'g_adj')
Thread 0 ('h', 'h_adj')
Thread 2 ('i', 'i_adj')
Thread 1 ('j', 'j_adj')
Thread 0 ('k', 'k_adj')
Thread 2 ('l', 'l_adj')
Thread 1 ('m', 'm_adj')
Thread 0 ('n', 'n_adj')
Thread 2 ('o', 'o_adj')
Thread 1 ('p', 'p_adj')
Thread 0 ends
End
```

What was missing in your code was :
`while not q_objects.empty():` in a worker thread so that it loops all
`..task_done()` in the workers so that the .join() is not blocking

Also, I added a time.sleep() to fake a duration, otherwise the first thread would have eaten up all the data in this simple example

---

[New edit to answer comment]
Well you just need to do :

```py
for obj in objects_list:
    q_objects.put([obj, get_obj_adj(obj)])
```

i.e adding a list of stuff as an object in the Queue.
Then in the worker, a simple `data = q_objects.get()` would retrieve this list of 2 elements. You access them with `data[0]` and `data[1]` :)

And in order for you to understand why it was not secure :
When you do `a = f1(), f2()`, f1 is computed first, then f2, then both result are put in a as a tuple. But the two computations of f1 and f2 happen the one after another.

In a threaded context, what could happen is :

```
 1. Thread0 : data = q_objects.get(), q_objects_adj.get()
 2. Thread0 : q_objects.get is computing
 3. Thread1 : data = q_objects.get(), q_objects_adj.get()
 4. Thread1 : q_objects.get is computing
```

And now... If the compute from thread1 finishes first, you are doomed, because here is what comes next :

```
 5. Thread1 : q_objects.get finishes and gives B (A is about to be given to Thread0 who asked first)
 6. Thread1 : q_objects_adj is now computing, and WILL give A_adj since it has never been asked yet
```

And the result is out of synchro : Thread0 will have A and B_adj, Thread1 will have B and A_adj

Note that this will happen only in the case when two threads ask exactly at the same time but... You know what, shit happens ^^

Comment: Thank you so much for your help but this is returning data for only the first 3 objects in the list objects_list. I want to have an output for all objects in objects_list, 3 (in parallel) by 3.

Comment: Ok I edited, please have a look :)

Comment: Excellent. This is all what I want. Thank you ^^

Comment: Ok nice. I don't know about your real project, but please note that you could have used one queue only, puting some lists of data to compute inside. Working with 2 queues is ok, but in the current context you need to know it's unsafe if you want a synchro. I mean here C could come with D_adj in a worker. There are a few chances but not 0%

Comment: Thank you. In my real project, `get_obj_adj` should return a correspondant dataframe of every letter in the  `objects_list` ( 'a' for example will have it's correspondant dataframe symbolized by `a_adj` in my code example). What is the best way to avoid the problem that you've mentioned please ? and keep the data synchronised ? can you add it in your code ?

Comment: I edited again :)

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, [`Queue.empty` is a function](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.empty); you'll need to call it.

```
while not q_objects.empty():
```

(The expression `not q_objects.empty` is always False since a function is truthy, so your threads never enter the loop.)

Comment: sorry, I miss wrote it and I tested without the loop (I updated my code). Still having the same problem. The program is still running forever.

Comment: And we still don't know what you want your program to do. Please let us know.

Comment: @quamrana I want `worker()` to be executed in parallel for every 3 objects simultaneously in the list `objects_list` (and not to execute it in parallel for all the objects in `objects_list`) and return every obj and its obj_adj. That's why I'm using multithreading.

Comment: Do you mean that each worker executes for their first object, but waits for the others to finish before their next object? Plus what do you mean by `"return every obj ... "`? Threads don't ever return anything.

Comment: @quamrana what I wanted to understand is how can I limit the maximum number of threads running at once giving the code that I've used above. I'm sorry, I'm new to multithreading, I'm trying to figure out how it works + I used the code mentioned in the documentation of Queue (please see link to the documentation in my post) but with arguments.

Comment: Ok, but note that the `def worker()` threads in the documentation never return anything. Also, `num_worker_threads` limits the number of threads created and you've used `3`, so you *are* limiting the number of threads.

Comment: Ok thank you, what I wanted to say by using 3 for num_worker_threads is to run in parallel 3 threads until finishing all the list of objects in `objects_list`: for example: running 3 threads in parallel for objects 'a', 'b', 'c' the running 3 threads in parallel for objects 'd', 'e', 'f' ... until finishing all the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern based around what it looks like you may be trying to achieve.

The key feature here is that the threads run continuously until some predetermined value is observed on the queue. Using None as the "stopper" value may not always be appropriate but is fine for this example.

```
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

NTHREADS = 3

# worker thread blocks on qa waiting for any data
# if received data is None (or equivalent) then the loop termunates and the thread ends
# if non-None data is received, do a blocking get() on qb
def worker(qa, qb, output):
    while a := qa.get():
        b = qb.get()
        output.append((a, b))

def main():
    # list of threads
    threads = []
    # the queues
    qa = Queue()
    qb = Queue()
    # this is where the output tuples go
    output = []

    # start all the threads and add each one to the thread list
    for _ in range(NTHREADS):
        (thread := Thread(target=worker, args=[qa, qb, output])).start()
        threads.append(thread)

    # send data to each queue
    for o in "abcdefghijklmnop":
        qa.put(o)
        qb.put(f"{o}_adj")

    # send None to qa - once for each thread
    # this tells the thread to terminate
    for _ in range(NTHREADS):
        qa.put(None)
    
    # wait for the threads to complete
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    # print the result
    print(*output, sep="\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
('a', 'a_adj')
('b', 'b_adj')
('c', 'c_adj')
('d', 'd_adj')
('e', 'e_adj')
('f', 'f_adj')
('g', 'g_adj')
('h', 'h_adj')
('i', 'i_adj')
('j', 'j_adj')
('k', 'k_adj')
('l', 'l_adj')
('m', 'm_adj')
('n', 'n_adj')
('o', 'o_adj')
('p', 'p_adj')
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always done this by putting the jobs in the `Queue` first (I use `SimpleQueue`), then starting the threads. The thread consists of a loop, `get`ting a job from the queue, until the get fails, then terminating. Finally, the main joins all of the threads before returning. Something like:

```
def worker( q ):
    try:
        while True:
            job = q.get( block = False )
            #   Do job, here just take some time and output the job
            time.sleep( random.randint( 1, 10 ) / 10 )
            print( '{}: {}'.format( threading.current_thread().name, job ) ); sys.stdout.flush()
    except queue.Empty:
        return

def main():
    q = queue.SimpleQueue()
    jobs = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' ]
    for j in jobs:
        q.put( j )
    threads = []
    for id in range( 3 ):
        threads.append( threading.Thread( name = str( id ), target = worker, args = (q, ) ) )
        threads[-1].start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

Of course, whether this or Codist's solution is more appropriate depends on the situation. In earlier work (in C++) I've also used solutions along the lines of what Codist suggests. The important points are:

- The threads loop as long as there is work to be done -- when there is
  no more work, this must be signaled, either by no more jobs being
  present in the list (simpler, but only appropriate if you can
  effectively fill the queue before starting the threads), or by some
  special signal or job. (In C++, I implemented the queue myself, and
  checked as separate flag in the `condition_wait`, so I didn't have to
  generate a lot of special jobs.)
- The threads must be joined (and should not be detached).

I find the above solution simpler, but it requires defining all of the jobs up front. Codist's solution allows actually waiting for jobs to arrive later, as a result of some external event.